# How to set the custom variables from different loaction(file) using Angular Js

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6 and see in `home.component.ts` file variable being defined at the beginning: `public hasResults = false;`

And then in `home.component.html` file - section for displaying:

```
<span style="padding-left:5px" [hidden]="hasResults">
    <ang-shortcut-display></ang-shortcut-display>
</span>
```

(which will display section once hasResults is not False anymore).

Now I need to have action on a Home Button to hide section again (I am assuming to set `hasResults` to False again).

How to set this variable `hasResults` to `False` again when e.g. someone hits Home button.

So far I found that action after hitting Home Button is in `home.component.ts`

```
homeRouteAction() {
    \\ set hasResults to false
}
```

but not sure if `hasResults` is visible at that moment and how properly to set it to false (pass value) so that can change value (and set above html section to hidden again)?

Comment: Are you looking for toggle functionality.                                       
homeRouteAction() {
    this.hasResults = !this.hasResults;
}

Comment: Thanks for the question. Looking to just set hasResults = 'false' but just not sure if should be enough to say this.hasResults (with this prefix) or there is another thing to do in order to make sure changing the value of hasResults is propagated?

Comment: If you want to set false, you can try homeRouteAction() { this.hasResults = false; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, you have two things you can pass this value in service or maintain local storage,

1. when you initiate this value that time you can call set value in service and when you need to call get user service using observable, rxjs

Answer (score 0):

You can set a method in your home.component.ts

```
setResults () {
    this.hasResults=false;
  }
```

and then, in the home.component.html call the method for it to propagate

```
(click)="setResults()"
```

Such as:

```
<a href="home" (click)="setResults()">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. There are 2 TS files above.. In which file should be set each, please?

Comment: Which two? In your question, you used home.component.html and home.component.ts, which is normal.

I have updated my answer, use the call function in the .html file, and declare the method in the TS file.